# Filtering "Smoothing" an array of numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, filter, smoothing

I am writing an application in X-code. It is gathering the sensor data (gyroscope) and then transforming it throw FFTW. At the end I am getting the result in an array. In the app. I am plotting the graph but there is so much peaks (see the graph in red) and i would like to smooth it.

[image]

My array:

```
double magnitude[S];
    ...
    magnitude[i]=sqrt((fft_result[i][0])*(fft_result[i][0])+ (fft_result[i][1])*(fft_result[i][1]) );
```

An example array (for 30 samples, normally I am working with 256 samples): 
"0.9261901713034604",
    "2.436272348237486",
    "1.618854900218465",
    "1.849221286218342",
    "0.8495016887742839",
    "0.5716796354304043",
    "0.4229791869017677",
    "0.3731843430827401",
    "0.3254446111798023",
    "0.2542702545675339",
    "0.25237940627189",
    "0.2273716541964159",
    "0.2012780334451323",
    "0.2116151847259499",
    "0.1921943719520009",
    "0.1982429400169304",
    "0.18001770452247",
    "0.1982429400169304",
    "0.1921943719520009",
    "0.2116151847259499",
    "0.2012780334451323",
    "0.2273716541964159",
    "0.25237940627189",
    "0.2542702545675339",
    "0.3254446111798023",
    "0.3731843430827401",
    "0.4229791869017677",
    "0.5716796354304043",
    "0.8495016887742839",
    "1.849221286218342"

How to filter /smooth it? whats about gauss? Any idea how to begin or even giving me a sample code. 
Thank you for your help!

best regards

josef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to smooth would be to replace each sample with the average of it and its 2 neighbors.

Comment: And whats about Gauss? isn't it more efficient?

Comment: Can't get much more efficient that 2 adds and a divide per sample.  Gauss might provide a *better* smoothing, but probably isn't any more efficient.

Comment: can you write me (editing in your answer) the code how to use gauss?

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest idea would be taking average of 2 points and putting them into an array. Something like

```
double smooth_array[S];

for (i = 0; i<S-2; i++)
    smooth_array[i]=(magnitude[i] + magnitude[i+1])/2;

smooth_array[S-1]=magnitude[S-1];
```

It is not best one, but I think it should be ok.

If you need the scientific approach - use some kind of approximation / approximation algorithms. Something like least squares function approximation or even full SE13/SE35 etc. algorithms.

Comment: Thanks Midas, you got your first vote up ;). Please read my comment @scott Hunter down.

Comment: Doesn't this "shift" the sample?  In some sense, the values you are computing should have an index of `i+(1/2)` (which makes more sense if these represent times or locations as opposed to just ordinals).

Comment: @ScottHunter
I didnt understand what u mean with i+(1/2) !!
can you please edit your answer and write me the correct code that I can accept. And if you know how to do it with gauss ( if its possible) please write it too. thanks a lot

Comment: If the data were a time series, where each index represented a particular point in time, then you are in effect computing the smoothed value for time `i` by averaging it with the value at time `i+1`, which could be interpreted as the value you'd expect for the time *between* `i` and `i+1` (hence, the `i+(1/2)`).

Comment: @ScottHunter I am computing the result of the FFTW, so its not anymore depending on time, so i think I use it, cannot I? but with : `for (i = 0; i<S-1; i++)`.